# Creating a composite primary key while one of the column may or may not be null

Tags: oracle10g, informatica-powercenter

Can anyone tell me how can I create unique keys by combining two columns when one of the column values may be null?

So lets say there are 2 col:-col1 and col2. I have to define a composite key on these two columns and how can I handle null values coming in any of these column?

Is there any way to randomly generate a value for any of the null column and than create a unique key in informatica?

Comment: How about making the other column a computed one? Or have third column that would be a computation of the first two and create unique key on the third one (if you can't modify col2 definition).

Answer (score 0):

Have a persisted sequence attached to the composite key (col1+col2+seq_no). For every run increment that key and store it's max and then in it's subsequent runs use max+1. For incremental sequence you can use sequence generator or can compute value using expression variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a DECODE to handle the NULL values in the COL1 and COL2.

Use Sequence generator to populate values in SEQ_VALUE port
Start from 1001 and increment by 1,

```
KEY_COL1 = DECODE(COL1,NULL,0,COL1)
--assigning to a variable port KEY_COL1

KEY_COL2 = DEOCDE(COL2,NULL,0,col2)
--assigning to a variable port KEY_COL2
```

Then generate a composite key

```
COMPOSITE_KEY = (SEQ_VALUE || KEY_COL1  || KEY_COL2 )
```

How it works:

[image]